# Segfault during custom collation creation sqlite using qt

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I'm trying to add a custom collating function into a qt project, using sqlite.
I'm getting a segfault that i don't understand, thus can't fix.

It comes from the following code, in the sqlite3_create_collation sql function.

```
bool create_collate(QSqlDatabase *db)
{
    QVariant v = db->driver()->handle();
    if (!v.isValid() || qstrcmp(v.typeName(), "sqlite3*") != 0)
        return -1;

    sqlite3* sql_db = *static_cast<sqlite3* const*>(v.data());
    if (!sql_db)
        return -1;

    sqlite3_initialize();
--> return sqlite3_create_collation(sql_db, "NOACCENTS", SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &localeCompare); <--
}
```

The segv happens when reaching this particular function, on the highlighted line:

```
static HashElem *findElementWithHash(
  const Hash *pH,     /* The pH to be searched */
  const char *pKey,   /* The key we are searching for */
  unsigned int *pHash /* Write the hash value here */
){
  HashElem *elem;                /* Used to loop thru the element list */
  unsigned int count;            /* Number of elements left to test */
  unsigned int h;                /* The computed hash */
  static HashElem nullElement = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

  if( pH->ht ){   /*OPTIMIZATION-IF-TRUE*/
    struct _ht *pEntry;
    h = strHash(pKey) % pH->htsize;
    pEntry = &pH->ht[h];
--> elem = pEntry->chain; <--
    count = pEntry->count;
  }else{
    h = 0;
    elem = pH->first;
    count = pH->count;
  }
  if( pHash ) *pHash = h;
  while( count-- ){
    assert( elem!=0 );
    if( sqlite3StrICmp(elem->pKey,pKey)==0 ){ 
      return elem;
    }
    elem = elem->next;
  }
  return &nullElement;
}
```

The output of `sqlite -version` is 3.32.3, which is consistent with the version used by qt, also 3.32.3.

EDIT:

localeCompare :

```
int localeCompare(void *, int len1, const void *data1, int len2, const void* data2)
{
    auto qstr1 = QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data1), len1 * 4);
    auto qstr2 = QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data2), len2 * 4);

    int end = 0;
    while (qstr1[end] != '\0') {end++;}
    qstr1.truncate(end + 1);

    end = 0;
    while (qstr2[end] != '\0') {end++;}
    qstr2.truncate(end + 1);

    return QString::compare(BkString::removeAccents(qstr1), BkString::removeAccents(qstr2), Qt::CaseInsensitive);
}
```

Qt has been installed via the online installer.

The corresponding .pro:

```
QT += core sql quick qml
QT -= gui

TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += unversioned_libname unversioned_soname # do not generate the symbolic link.

!android {
    LIBS += -lsqlite3 -ldl
}
TARGET = bkdatabase-core

INCLUDEPATH += ./src

SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ...
```

A minimal example would be:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

int main(void)
{
   QSqlDatabase db("QSQLITE");
   db.setDataBaseName("My_db");

   if (db.open())
      create_collate(&db);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed Qt using the online installer then it has been compiled not using the system sqlite so you have to download the sqlite amalgation (the version of sqlite depends on the version that was used to compile Qt which you can get using `SELECT sqlite_version()`, in Qt 5.15 you get 3.31.1 so you have to download https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-amalgamation-3310100.zip. You can also find out this information by checking the [qt_attribution.json](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/3rdparty/sqlite/qt_attribution.json?h=5.15.0) file in the source code.

```
├── 3rdParty
│   ├── sqlite
│   │   ├── shell.c
│   │   ├── sqlite3.c
│   │   ├── sqlite3ext.h
│   │   └── sqlite3.h
│   └── sqlite.pri
├── 64591348.pro
└── main.cpp
```

***.pro**

```
QT -= gui
QT += sql
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle


SOURCES += main.cpp

include(3rdParty/sqlite.pri)
```

**sqlite.pri**

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/sqlite

SOURCES += $$PWD/sqlite/sqlite3.c
LIBS += -ldl
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlDriver>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QDebug>

#include <sqlite3.h>

int localeCompare(void *, int len1, const void *data1, int len2, const void* data2)
{
    auto qstr1 = QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data1), len1 * 4);
    auto qstr2 = QString::fromUtf8(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data2), len2 * 4);

    int end = 0;
    while (qstr1[end] != '\0') {end++;}
    qstr1.truncate(end + 1);

    end = 0;
    while (qstr2[end] != '\0') {end++;}
    qstr2.truncate(end + 1);

    return QString::compare(qstr1, qstr2, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
}

bool create_collate(QSqlDatabase db)
{
    QVariant v = db.driver()->handle();
    if (!v.isValid() || qstrcmp(v.typeName(), "sqlite3*") != 0)
        return false;

    sqlite3* sql_db = *static_cast<sqlite3* const*>(v.data());
    if (!sql_db)
        return false;

    sqlite3_initialize();
    return sqlite3_create_collation(sql_db, "NOACCENTS", SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &localeCompare) == SQLITE_OK;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_UNUSED(argc)
    Q_UNUSED(argv)
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
    if(!db.open())
        return -1;
    QSqlQuery q;
    if(!q.exec("SELECT sqlite_version()")){
        qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
        return -1;
    }
    if(q.first()){
        qDebug() << q.value(0).toString();
    }
    if(!create_collate(db))
        return -1;
    if(!q.exec("CREATE TABLE test(x)")){
        qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
        return -1;
    }
    q.prepare("INSERT into test(x) values (?)");
    for(const QString & word: {"z", "a", "p"}){
        q.addBindValue(word);
        if(!q.exec()){
            qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if(!q.exec("SELECT x FROM test ORDER BY x COLLATE NOACCENTS")){
        qDebug() << q.lastError().text();
        return -1;
    }
    while (q.next()) {
        qDebug() << q.value(0).toString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
"3.31.1"
"a"
"p"
"z"
```

Comment: That was it, I was checking the sqlite version the wrong way, thanks for the tip and the help!